# Finding constant C in Big-Oh notation

Tags: algorithm, performance, data-structures, time, big-o

I'm having trouble finding a constant C that works for the following problems:

`18 n2 + 122 n = O( n2)          find a C ≤ 50 

11 n2 + 132 n + 390 = O( n2)    find a C ≤ 20`

> "Using the definition of O, prove each part. Choose an explicit positive integer constant C within theindicated range and solve for a positive integer K which is as small as possible."

I understand that `18 n2 + 122 n <= c n2 , n >= k`

Comment: In both cases you benefit from a c the highest possible. The higher the c, the lower the k you will find

Comment: [Plot for first](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=18n%5E2+%2B+122n+%3C%3D+50+n%5E2) and [plot for second](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=11n%5E2+%2B+132n+%2B+390+%3C%3D+20n%5E2). Just write down the equation, using the maximal allowed `C` and compute a `k` for which it starts to hold. It's `61/16` for the first (greater equals `4`) and `1/3 (22 + sqrt(874))` for the second (greater equals `18`).

Comment: Pick any value for C, solve for n. If you picked the wrong C, trying to solve for n should reveal the problem and how to fix it (but there are quite a lot of values for C which will work). Also, it's `<= c.n^2`, not `= c.n^2`. Most of this is just elementary algebra - if you haven't been taught that yet, you'll probably have a hard time with a whole bunch of things going forward.

Comment: Okay, the second one might not be quite that easy (but maybe if you pick the right C? ... and actually know how to do factorisation).

Answer (score 0):

Might as well just increment the coefficient on the dominant power, and use **19** and **12**. Then:

**18k² + 122k <= 19k²**

**⇔ 122k <= k²**

**⇔ k >= 122 or k <= 0**

**11k² + 132k + 390 <= 12k²**

**⇔ k² - 132k - 390 >= 0**

You could use the quadratic formula for that one, but I would just start at **k=133** and count upwards